# Finding Part Number that doesn't have Invoice Number in Pandas Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have 2 pandas dataframes that look like this:

Dataframe 1:

| customer | sales | invoice no | product sub category | part number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | John | 123 | SubA | P01 |
| B | John | 456 | SubB | P02 |
| C | John | 789 | SubC | P03 |
| D | John | 1011 | SubC | P04 |
| E | John | 1213 | SubA | P05 |

Dataframe 2:

| product sub category | part number |
| --- | --- |
| SubA | P01 |
| SubA | P05 |
| SubB | P02 |
| SubB | P06 |
| SubC | P03 |
| SubC | P04 |

I want to check the `part number` that doesn't have `invoice no` per `customer`.

I have tried this code, but it returns empty dataframe:

```
# merge 2 dataframes
product = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'part number', how = 'outer')

# checking part number without invoice number
not_sold = product[product['invoice no'].isna()]

# grouping part number without invoice number per customer
not_sold_per_customer = not_sold.groupby('customer')['part'].agg(lambda x: ', '.join(x.drop_duplicates())).reset_index()
```

this is the desired output:

| customer | part number |
| --- | --- |
| A | P02, P03, P04, P05 |
| B | P01, P03, P04, P05 |
| C | P01, P02, P04, P05 |
| D | P01, P02, P03, P05 |
| E | P01, P02, P03, P04 |

please help me build the right code. thank u in advance!

Comment: Is order important in new column?

Comment: nope, it's not important at all

Comment: Super, so my solution working well?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#get common values between both DataFrames
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'part number')
#convert valeus to sets
s = set(df['part number'])

#join all sets without value from row
df1['part number'] = [', '.join(s - {x}) for x in df1['part number']]
print (df1)
  customer sales  invoice no product sub category         part number
0        A  John         123                 SubA  P05, P03, P02, P04
1        B  John         456                 SubB  P05, P03, P04, P01
2        C  John         789                 SubC  P05, P01, P02, P04
3        D  John        1011                 SubC  P05, P03, P02, P01
4        E  John        1213                 SubA  P03, P02, P04, P01
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you want. It creates two columns dataframe with customer name and part number if that customer/order has no invoice.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'customer':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c'],'sale':['John', 'Dan', 'Will', 'Bill', 'John'],'invoices':[123, 234, np.nan, 789, np.nan], 
                    'product category': ['Suba', 'Subb', 'Subc', 'Subd', 'Subx'], 'part number':['Po1', 'Po2', 'Po3', 'Po4', 'Po5']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'product category': ['Suba', 'Subb', 'Subc', 'Subd', 'Subx'], 'part number':['Po1', 'Po2', 'Po3', 'Po4', 'Po5']})

df3 = df1.merge(df2, on = ['product category', 'part number'])
columns_to_drop = ['product category', 'sale', 'invoices']
df3 = df3.loc[df3.invoices.isna()]

df3.drop(columns_to_drop, axis=1, inplace=True)
df3 = df3.groupby('customer')['part number'].apply(list)
df3 = df3.to_frame()
df3['customer'] = df3.index
df3 = df3[['customer', 'part number']]
df3=df3.reset_index(drop=True)

def to_string(x):
    return ' '.join(str(e) for e in x)
df3['part number'] = df3['part number'].apply(to_string)

print(df3)
```

### OUTPUT

```
  customer part number
0        c     Po3 Po5
```

If you do not use apply method you part number column will contain a list of  part numbers instead of a string.